# Error: Expected unqualified-id before 'protected' in code

Tags: c++, c

I'm trying to compile a part of the code of cowpatty on my own, but my compiler always stumbles over the following code:

```
struct dot11hdr {
    union {
        struct {
            uint8_t     version:2;
            uint8_t     type:2;
            uint8_t     subtype:4;
            uint8_t     to_ds:1;
            uint8_t     from_ds:1;
            uint8_t     more_frag:1;
            uint8_t     retry:1;
            uint8_t     pwrmgmt:1;
            uint8_t     more_data:1;
            uint8_t     protected:1;
            uint8_t     order:1;
        } __attribute__ ((packed)) fc;

        uint16_t    fchdr;
    } u1;

    uint16_t    duration;
    uint8_t     addr1[6];
    uint8_t     addr2[6];
    uint8_t     addr3[6];

    union {
        struct {
            uint16_t    fragment:4;
            uint16_t    sequence:12;
        } __attribute__ ((packed)) seq;

        uint16_t    seqhdr;
    } u2;

} __attribute__ ((packed));
```

Here I get the error `error: expected unqualified-id before 'protected'` for the line `uint8_t protected:1;`. Why? When compiling the full code with the given main-file, everything works. I already included every cflag and ldflag in my own makefile to prevent errors related to missing cflags.

Comment: `protected` is a keyword in C++.

Comment: That should be obvious.

Comment: After renaming the keyword, everything worked...

Comment: @arc_lupus: why don't you use the corresponding compiler instead of renaming?

Comment: Because I wanted to use some cpp-functions, too...

Answer (score 0):

Cowpatty is written in C and you need to compile it as such. As noted in the comments`protected`is a keyword in C++ and compiling it as C++ code won't work.

Check your compiler documentation to see what flag you should use to compile as C (or use a C compiler like GCC, the error suggests that you are using G++ at the moment).

Answer (score 0):

You need to build your project with a C compiler rather than C++, otherwise you enter the world of surprise. They are not compatible forth and back anymore, and in this sense that the `protected` is a C++ keyword, they have never been.

Make sure that you use gcc or a similar C compiler *without* g++ or the c++ runtime library when compiling. Once you fix that, the compiler will not raise issue because protected is not a keyword in the C language.

In general, C projects should avoid using keywords in C++, or even types from the standard library, like string, et cetera.

If it is not a public API, nor is it risky to rename this variable internally everywhere without much risk, you could convince upstream to rename it to be more C++ friendly, but there is no guarantee that it would go far.